# Why do I need css-loader?

Tags: webpack-4

I am new to webpack.

Can anyone give me a simple explanation of why we do need the css loader? Can't I simply keep adding css file references into html  tag?

I could find information only about HOW TO use css loader, but WHY I should use it.

I suspect it can be useful for lazy loading but not sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Webpack transforms EVERYTHING into js, and everything is considered a module for webpack. You need something to be able to translate/transform that js"css" into useful css.

That is the only reason.